# How to display Text on a PieChart?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, text, pie-chart

I have Created a PieChart Using the following Code. Here, I Have taken the sum of `x` and `y` as 100% to display the `x%` as red color and `y%` as green color on pieChart.

On the red color i want to display the exact `x%` (Example `45%` (or) `55%`) and on the green color i want to display the exact `y%` (Example `55%` (or) `45%`).

In my application the `X` and `Y` values are Variables. Those Values are changing each time when i run my application. I want to display the pieChart with green and red colors with the percentage on those regions. How Can i make frames to display percentages on that regions?

**.m file**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code

 int x = 25;
 int y = 42;

 float sum = x + y;
 float mult = (360/sum);

 float startDeg = 0;
 float endDeg = 0;

 int x = 74;
 int y = 60;
 int r = 60;

 CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
 CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);

 startDeg = 0;
 endDeg = (x * mult);
 if(startDeg != endDeg)
 {
 CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0);
 CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, x, y);
 CGContextAddArc(ctx, x, y, r, (startDeg)*M_PI/180.0, (endDeg)*M_PI/180.0, 0);
 CGContextClosePath(ctx);
 CGContextFillPath(ctx);
 }

 startDeg = endDeg;
 endDeg = endDeg + (y * mult);
 if(startDeg != endDeg)
 {
 CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
 CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, x, y);
 CGContextAddArc(ctx, x, y, r, (startDeg)*M_PI/180.0, (endDeg)*M_PI/180.0, 0);
 CGContextClosePath(ctx);
 CGContextFillPath(ctx);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw a string with NSString drawInRect during the drawRect method.  For example:

```
[percentageString drawInRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, 30, 20) 
                    withFont:font 
               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip 
                   alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

**Update**

Here is how to find the x, y for placing text:

```
CGFloat startDegree = 180;                             // start at 180
CGFloat endDegree = degree;                            // end at some value

CGFloat mid = (endDegree + startDegree) / 2;           // find midpoint
CGFloat rad = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(mid);                 // convert to radians


// center is center of pie chart
// radius is how big the pie chart is
// 30 is extra to draw text outside circle

CGFloat x =  center.x + ((radius + 30) * cos(rad));    
CGFloat y = center.y + ((radius + 30) * sin(rad));

NSLog(@"X Y: %f %f %f", x, y, degree);

NSString *text = @"Test";   
[text drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, y, 50, 44) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
```

I had a sample pie chart so I used that.  It has a slider with degrees.  In the example, I can draw a segment of the pie chart from 180 degrees to 360 degrees.

Comment: In my piechart the main problem is i'm not able to know the coordinates.. The green and red regions are changing depends on x% and y%... if x% is 60.. i want to display 60% in on the X region... if x% is 20.. i want to display 20% with in that 20% area.. Here the coordinates of rectangle which is having percentage value are changing.. In the above answer you are giving fixed coordinates (100,100)... That is the main problem for me... If you have another souce code to draw pieChart with text. Please let me know.... Thank u..

Comment: @SriKanth I updated my answer to show how to find the x and y coordinates for placing the text.

Comment: Thank you Very much.. I hope now it will come.. I'm trying it... But DEGREES_TO_RADIANS Method Showing an Error that "Implicit Declaration of Function DEGREES_TO_RADIANS is invalid in c99".. I am doing this in iOS5... Without that method i am converting degrees to radians... it is fine.. Is there any method in iOS5 to convert it...

Comment: #define   DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees)  ((M_PI * degrees)/ 180)