# how to show percent % with value on pie chart in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am creating a pie chart in iPhone app it works fine but i want also to show the percentage of each section with like 17% 25% etc.

I am using following code

```
-(void)createGraph
{
    PieClass *myPieClass=[[PieClass alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,440,320,230)];
    myPieClass.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    myPieClass.itemArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:valueOne,valueTwo,valueThree,valueFour, nil];
    myPieClass.myColorArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIColor blueColor],[UIColor redColor],[UIColor greenColor],[UIColor brownColor], nil];
    myPieClass.radius=100;
    [self.view addSubview:myPieClass];
}
```

Pie Class

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   @interface PieClass : UIView 
   {
          NSArray* itemArray;
          NSArray* myColorArray; 
          int radius;
   }

  @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray* itemArray;
  @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray* myColorArray;
  @property(nonatomic,assign) int radius;

  @end

  #import "PieClass.h"
  @implementation PieClass
  @synthesize itemArray,myColorArray,radius;

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
    // Initialization code
   }
   return self;
 }
```

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
   // Drawing code
   int c=[itemArray count];
   CGFloat angleArray[c];
   CGFloat offset;
   int sum=0;

   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
   CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, false);
   CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, false);

   for(int i=0;i<[itemArray count];i++)
          sum+=[[itemArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

   for(int i=0;i<[itemArray count];i++)
   {
          angleArray[i]=(float)(([[itemArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue])/(float)sum)*(2*3.14); // in radians
           CGContextMoveToPoint(context, radius, radius);
           if(i==0)
               CGContextAddArc(context, radius, radius, radius, 0,angleArray[i], 0);
           else
               CGContextAddArc(context, radius, radius, radius,offset,offset+angleArray[i], 0);
           offset+=angleArray[i];

           CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, ((UIColor *)[myColorArray objectAtIndex:i]).CGColor);
           CGContextClosePath(context); 
           CGContextFillPath(context);
    }
 }
```

Comment: possible dupe of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384425/how-to-display-text-on-a-piechart

Comment: @rishi my is a little bit difference can u help me how to solve my probelm if you can